# Ко/контрвариантность у делегата

Tags: c#, делегаты

Есть такой делегат

```
delegate void Del(string z);
```

И ему присваивается метод

```
public void Foo(object z)
{

}
```

Присваивание происходит нормально, за счет вариантности. Однако если в параметре делегата стринг поменять на int тогда компилятор уже возмущается. Почему ? Полагаю, что это как-то связано с ссылочным/структурным типом. Но ведь все они идут от object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы правы, вариантность делегатов ограничена ссылочными типами.

Вот нормативная цитата из C# language reference (лежит в `<Visual Studio install dir>\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx`), раздел 15.2 (перевод мой):

## 15.2 Совместимость делегатов

Метод или делегат `M` называется ***совместимым*** с делегатным типом `D`, если выполняются следующие условия:

- У `D` и `M` одинаковое количество параметров, и каждый параметр в `D` имеет одинаковые модификаторы `ref`/`out`, как и соответствующий параметр в `M`.
- Для каждого параметра, не содержащего `ref`/`out`, существует тождественное преобразование (§6.1.1) или неявное ссылочное преобразование (§6.1.6) из типа параметра в `D` в тип соответствующего параметра в `M`.
- Для каждого `ref`-/`out`-параметра, тип параметра в `D` в точности тот же, что и в `M`.
- Существует тождественное или неявное ссылочное преобразование из возвращаемого типа в `M` к возвращаемому типу в `D`.

---

Это значит, что типы параметром должны быть либо одинаковы (с точностью до разницы между `object` и `dynamic`), либо тип параметра должен быть ссылочным подтипом типа параметра в `D`. Это исключает значимые типы.